# Hiding a component within a Border-Layout region programatically

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have a border Layout with let's say two regions; center and west. The westregion is added with the splitter param and is collapsible. Now I have a toolbar from which I want to hide/show the west region. I've solved this by calling the `toggleTargetCmp()` method of the splitter. Well I know, this is a private method and should not be used, but I found no other way to archive this. So far so good. All this works.

But now I want to hide the splitter & placeholder (I fetch the placeholder ownet by using the `getCollapseTarget()` method of the splitter) if the button in the toolbar gets clicked. I tried it with `setVisible(false)` which works for the splitter but it didn't work well for the placeholder... after a deeper look onto the placeholder instance I can tell that it is set to `hidden: true` but it uses the `hideMode: 'offsets'` by default plus `hiddenAnchestor: false` which is not documented in the API.

Based on the API docu for **[hideMode](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-hideMode)** I tried to set it to `'display'`
before calling `setVisible(false)` without any luck, the placeholder still stays visible.

So how can I hide the placholder, too. Or is there even a better way to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried hide method? It works exactly as you describe - hides region and splitter.
In my project I do it like this:

```
panel.hide();
```

where panel is one of borderPanel items.

Comment: Based on the [API hide()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-hide) is only valid for floating elements. But I will give it a try.

Comment: Well, sometimes it is good to reread the lines :) Just the animationTarget is restricted. Thanks for pointing me on that! +1

Comment: hide() hides the component but does not remove the placeholder.. how to remove the placeholder